# How to detect and print the encoding of a list of .sql files in a particular directory?

Tags: c#, encoding, streamreader, streamwriter

I have a list of .sql files that need to checked for their encoding before i make changes to them. They are either in utf 8 or utf 16. How can I make some changes to my code so that it `enter code here`reads the file and prints out on the Console what type of encoding the data in the file have?

My code now looks like below:

````
string sql = "E:\\src_Vemala\\Nautilus\\Product\\dev\\Database\\Nautilus\\Scripts\\ForwardDeclaration.sql";
     
for (int i = 0; i < sql.Length; i++)
           {


 //reads each line
               string[] ReadText = File.ReadAllLines(sql);
               using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sql))
               {
                   foreach (String s in ReadText)
                   {
       //carries out a particular function
                       sw.WriteLine(ReplaceView(s)); ```
````

Comment: Why do you want to check that in the first place? Have you encountered any actual problem? Or are you trying to save the new text using the same encoding as the old? `File.ReadAllLines` already tries to detect the encoding by checking for a Byte Order Mark.

Comment: i need to overwrite some content  in the documents ...when i overwrite some of the contents are changed from utf 16 to utf 8 and the file becomes unreadable. How can I overcome this Problem?

Comment: Don't try to overwrite just part of a file. You can't really. Files are written byte by byte, not line by line. If you write less than the original file, the old bytes remain. If you write a longer line than the one before, it will overwrite the new line. The only way to safely write to just part of a file is to have fixed-length records/lines and write at specific byte offsets.